# Since it's not possible to edit the Android Manifest programmatically, then it's not possible to create and use classes of 'Service' programatically?

Tags: java, android, reflection, service, manifest

A bit of context:
I have a generic android `Service` in which basically the user can personalise the tasks.
To keep track of these tasks (which are instances of `Thread`) I could either make a view inside my MainActivity layout or I would need to show multiple notifications, each for thread that is running.
I have been advised to avoid multiple notifications for a single service, hence the only  solution would be showing the progress inside the MainActivity.

Actual question:
I thought about another solution. I could dynamically create and compile the .`class` file and then use java reflection to use that external class. With this approach I would have distinct services (and therefore a single notification for each service) for each separate task.
However the issue is that in order to use a service I would need to declare it in the manifest file and as far as I know it's not possible to edit the manifest programmatically.
Unless its' possible to run an instance of a Service without declaring it into the manifest file?

Comment: First, what you want to do is not possible. Second, you are misunderstanding the recommendation. The recommendation is not "only have one notification per service" for an app. The recommendation is "only have one notification" for an app.

Comment: I understand. So, if it's the recommendation is only one notification per app, I guess to let the user handle (like stopping a task) the list of threads inside my service I would need a View inside my MainActivity layout?
 Would you mind telling me if I should keep using Service or "migrate" to WorkManager: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77955950/would-i-need-to-use-workmanager-instead-of-service-for-these-case-scenarios

Thanks so much.

Comment: "to let the user handle (like stopping a task) the list of threads inside my service I would need a View inside my MainActivity layout?" -- it would need to be in your app's UI. Whether that involves a layout or not depends on what you are using to build the UI (views or composables).

Comment: Yes, I don't use Jetpack. Thanks for the reply. Would you able to suggest me if I should "migrate" from service to WorkManager?